# How to change the value of a variable at some point lying in the time interval of solver in solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy

The following code solves a differential equation with `scipy`:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

t0 = 0
Z0 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
sw = 0
t_final = .001
t, z = t0, Z0
if sw == 0:
    sol = solve_ivp(f0, [t,t_final], z, method='BDF', events=g0)
    Z = sol.y.T
    t, z = sol.t[-1], Z[-1]
else:
    sol = solve_ivp(f1, [t,t_final], z, method='BDF', events=g1)
```

where `f0` and `f1` are the following functions:

```py
def f0(t, Z):
    U = np.array([[vin], [vdon]])
    Zdot = A*Z + B*U
    return Zdot

def f1(t, Z):
    U = np.array([[vin], [vdon]])
    Zdot = R*Z + S*U
    return Zdot
```

In the interval `[t0,t_final]` (i.e., `[0,.001]`), I want to change the value of `vin` in `U = np.array([[vin], [vdon]])` at `t=.0005` and onwards.
To be precise, for times `[.0005,.001]`, I want to put a different value for `vin`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several ways to go about doing this, but one simple solution is to define `f0` (and `f1`) so that `vin` depends on `t`. For example,

```py
def f0(t, Z):
    vin = vin_1 if t < 0.0005 else vin_2
    U = np.array([[vin], [vdon]])
    return A*Z + B*U
```

You have to define `vin_1` and `vin_2` elsewhere, but that should do it. In fact, `vin` could be a function of `t`, which would allow you to *gradually* change the value of `vin` throughout the integration if you wanted. Example:

```py
vin = lambda t: t*(1 - t)

def f0(t, Z):
    U = np.array([[vin(t)], [vdon]])
    return A*Z + B*U
```